# Existence of Inverse Fourier Transform for a function

Tags: calculus, fourier-transform, harmonic-functions, harmonic-numbers

For the function (all variables real, and $m>0$)

$f(x) = \frac{m}{\sqrt{\lambda }} \tanh \left(\frac{m \sqrt{x^2}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$,

the Fourier Transform is given by (result from Mathematica, for all variables being real) as

$\displaystyle{\frac{\sqrt{2 \pi } m \delta (p)}{\sqrt{\lambda }}+\frac{H_{\frac{1}{4} \left(\frac{i \sqrt{2} p}{m}-2\right)}}{2 \sqrt{\pi } \sqrt{\lambda }}+\frac{H_{\frac{1}{4} \left(-\frac{i p \sqrt{2}}{m}-2\right)}}{2 \sqrt{\pi } \sqrt{\lambda }}-\frac{H_{\frac{i p}{2 \sqrt{2} m}}}{2 \sqrt{\pi } \sqrt{\lambda }}-\frac{H_{-\frac{i p}{2 \sqrt{2} m}}}{2 \sqrt{\pi } \sqrt{\lambda }}}$

where $H$ is Harmonic Number.

Question 1: Does the inverse Fourier Transform (edited: of the resulting FT) exist, given the restrictions on the arguments of $H$?

Question 2: Does this imply that inverse Fourier Transform may not exist, even if the forward transform does exist?

Just in case, Mathematica will not evaluate the inverse FT of the result shown above.

Comment: Are you asking about the IFT of $f$ or about the IFT of the FT of $f$?

Comment: IFT of the FT of f (now the post is updated to clarify). Would expect the IFT of FT of f to give back f, unless the IFT is not defined. In the latter case, does that mean the FT exists just one way?

Comment: As an improper integral, the direct transform doesn't exist ($\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{i p x} \tanh |x| \, dx$ diverges). In the distributional sense, $f$ and $\mathcal F^{-1}[\mathcal F[f]]$ are the same functional.

Comment: Hi Maxim,
Could you please elaborate "in the distributional sense...are the same functional", and why "direct transform..." doesn't exist? 
For e.g. if the function shown is a solution for a differential equation, the FT of this function does satisfy the FT of the differential equation as well. 

Would this be somewhat different from the case of FT of tan(x), also in the sense of generalized functions? Thank you.

Comment: How do you define the FT? If as an integral, the Fourier integral of $\tanh |x|$ doesn't exist. If by extending the Plancherel theorem to tempered distributions (a distribution is another term for a generalized function), this automatically defines the inverse transform for any $F$: set $(f, \phi) = (F, \mathcal F^{-1}[\phi])$ and verify that $\mathcal F[f] = F$.